# Name and description of multiple debian packages with CMake and CPack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am currently trying to generate more than one debian package from my project. My only problem with this is setting the name, description, group and so forth of the packages.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Required CMake version
# --------------------------------------------------------------
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Project name
# --------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT (MyProject)


# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Find all source and header files
# --------------------------------------------------------------
FILE (GLOB all_H "*.h")
FILE (GLOB all_SRC "*.cpp")

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Set compiler flags
# --------------------------------------------------------------
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -O0 -g3")

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Add a shared library
# --------------------------------------------------------------
ADD_LIBRARY (mylib SHARED ${all_H} ${all_SRC})

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure components
# --------------------------------------------------------------
SET (CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Install
# --------------------------------------------------------------
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION ../lib COMPONENT main)
INSTALL(FILES ${all_H} DESTINATION ../include COMPONENT dev)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# CPack package and package_source targets
# --------------------------------------------------------------
SET (CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ;DEB")
SET (CPACK_SET_DESTDIR ON)

SET (CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "mypackage")
SET (CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "me")
SET (CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "this is my package description")

SET (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "this is my package description
 here comes detailed description text.")

INCLUDE (CPack)
```

The [manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aCPackComponent) has some properties and commands for CPack Components but I doesn't seem to find the right ones or the right place to change at least name and description for every single package/component.

I tried using `SET (CPACK_COMPONENT_MAIN_DISPLAY_NAME "main display name")` and `SET (CPACK_COMPONENT_main_DISPLAY_NAME "main display name")` as well as cpack_add_component() before INCLUDE(CPack) (which gives me an error) and after (which seems to be ignored).

Did anybody get this to work and knows the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi, could you please share your experience on this topic? Have you succeeded to build multiple deb packages?

Answer (score 1):

From last few days I am searching for such solution.
Let me first explain first my requirement and then how did i managed to solve problem.

I want to create 4 package from my single project

1. **Master package**: Which contains all binary,static/shared libraries,header files,configuration files and scripts.
2. **Runtime package**: Which contains only executable which are required to run my application i.e. binary ,shared library and scripts.
3. **Configuration package**: Which contains basic skeleton and place holder for configuration file.
4. **Development packages**: Which contains shared/static library and header files.

Generating Master package is easy one and straight forward. But If I use that way then I am unable to use other packages. So after struggling and scraping documents and mail archives, I came to one solution or workaround.

In my solution I am creating One extra custom target for each package I want to create. On that target I am creating other cmake project, which has list of files(Absolute location of file) to be install in that package, build that project and last create package by calling cpack.

[Here](https://github.com/manthanrtilva/CMake-Debian) is my solution.

There may be better/scale-able solution than this, If any one come across that please let me know.

Comment: Functionality for better component packaging was gradually added in CMake 3.5 on so bumping the version of your CPack and setting the variables described here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CPackDeb.html should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but in CMake before version 3.5 components packaging was not supported for CPack debian packages.

From version 3.5 on quite a few per component features were added so the easiest way to solve you problem would be to bump the version of CMake and set the variables described in the documentation:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/CPackDeb.html or a newer one
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CPackDeb.html