# change cpack generated name for component RPMs

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack

I am trying to create an RPM installer using cpack (via cmake) that creates multiple RPM files. I've almost got it working but the last remaining stumbling block is controlling the package names.
Specifically **I want to control where the component name appears in the RPM file name**.

Here is my experimental `CMakeLists.txt` file which installs `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` to two different packages "myproject-foo" & "myproject-bar".
I want the RPMs to follow my own naming conventions (actually I want conventions that are more FSH friendly) but **for some reason cmake insists on adding the component name at the end**. So I get:

```
myproject-comp-1.0.i686-foo.rpm
myproject-comp-1.0.i686-bar.rpm
```

rather than:

```
myproject-compfoo-1.0.i686.rpm
myproject-compbar-1.0.i686.rpm
```

I notice it names the source RPMs "more correctly":
E.g.

```
>rpm -qip <package> | grep source
Source RPM  : myproject-foo-1.0-1.src.rpm
```

Though I do not actually want a source RPM at all (is there a way to blank this field?)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

message("CMAKE_VERSION=${CMAKE_VERSION}")

SET(DOCDIR "doc")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_COMPONENT_NAME "core")
install(FILES foo.txt COMPONENT foo DESTINATION "${RPMBUILDROOT}${DOCDIR}")
install(FILES bar.txt COMPONENT bar DESTINATION "${RPMBUILDROOT}${DOCDIR}")

project(myproject CXX)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "myproject")
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION 1.0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "some org")

set(CPACK_COMPONENT_foo_DESCRIPTION "the foo component")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_bar_DESCRIPTION "the bar component")

# mentioned in cpack docs but doesn't seem to do anything here
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_foo_DISPLAY_NAME "foo display name?")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_bar_DISPLAY_NAME "foo display name?")

set(CPACK_COMPONENT_bar_DEPENDS foo)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "describe the complete suite of stuff")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/README.txt)

# added in cmake 3.6?
set(CPACK_RPM_foo_PACKAGE_SUMMARY "describe the foo package")
set(CPACK_RPM_bar_PACKAGE_SUMMARY "describe the bar package")
set(CPACK_RPM_foo_PACKAGE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-foo")
set(CPACK_RPM_bar_PACKAGE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-bar")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/README.txt)

#set(CPACK_RPM_foo_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-foo-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}.i686")
#set(CPACK_RPM_bar_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-bar-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}.i686")


set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-comp${CPACK_COMPONENT_DISPLAY_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}.i686")

set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "i686")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE TRUE)

include(CPack)

cpack_add_component(foo
                    DISPLAY_NAME foo comp
                    DESCRIPTION this is the foocomp)
cpack_add_component(bar
                    DISPLAY_NAME bar comp
                    DESCRIPTION this is the bar comp
            DEPENDS foo)
```

It seems like `CPACK_PACKAGE_<component>_FILE_NAME` `or CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` is not quite working.
I've tried with both cmake 3.4.3 and the latest (3.9.0 at the time of writing) as there is some suggestion of [fixes to component based installs in 3.6.0](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12997)

There is no such variable as the `CPACK_COMPONENT_DISPLAY_NAME` I've used in `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME`. Also something in cmake adds the component name to the end automatically.

There is a similar question for .deb packages from long ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600848/name-and-description-of-multiple-debian-packages-with-cmake-and-cpack?rq=1) but I would rather avoid such a complex solution if possible.
It would be easier to rename the packages after generation (but still feel hacky).

I also note that the package dependency `set(CPACK_COMPONENT_bar_DEPENDS foo)` is not recorded in the bar package.

#### Update: 01-Aug-2017

I've added a bug report for cmake [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17120) as to my mind there is a bug in the implementation of CPACK_RPM_`<component>`_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME. At the very least the documentation is insufficiently helpful.

Comment: Had this problem when was doing debs. Just gave up on it and made some shell scripts to fix the names and do some other tricky stuff.

Comment: Could you complete your question with a working solution? I can't get my code to work, whatever I do with `CPACK_RPM_<component>_FILE_NAME`, it keeps using `RPM-DEFAULT` (using CMake 3.13.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of there is a large note at the top of the documentation:

> Note
>
> part of variables is preferred to be in upper case (for e.g. if component is named foo then use CPACK_RPM_FOO_XXXX variable name format) as is with other CPACK__XXXX variables. For the purposes of back compatibility (CMake/CPack version 3.5 and lower) support for same cased component (e.g. fOo would be used as CPACK_RPM_fOo_XXXX) is still supported for variables defined in older versions of CMake/CPack but is not guaranteed for variables that will be added in the future. For the sake of back compatibility same cased component variables also override upper cased versions where both are present.

So if you have a component named foo, FOO, fOo... the variables are CPACK_RPM_FOO_... otherwise the variables will be ignored - Note that this is the case since the beginning of CPack's existance for the common component variables e.g. `CPACK_COMPONENT_foo_DESCRIPTION` <- foo part must be in upper case.

Next to the file names - before CPack 3.6 it was not possible to change file names without getting an error and having to copy the generated package manually. Since that version you can set the file name as you like or request the platform specific package name (defined by rpm installation) by setting `CPACK_RPM_FILE_NAME` or `CPACK_RPM_<component>_FILE_NAME` to `RPM-DEFAULT`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackRPM.html?highlight=cpack_rpm_file_name#variable:CPACK_RPM_FILE_NAME

Also `set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-comp${CPACK_COMPONENT_DISPLAY_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}.i686")` won't work as `${CPACK_COMPONENT_DISPLAY_NAME}` is not an anchor and is automatically replaced on that location - not set by you so replacement text is an empty string... So if you really want to set the name manually you should set the RPM packager equivalent of that variable `CPACK_RPM_<component>_FILE_NAME` for each and every component (so you'll need a for loop or some more copy pasting...) - note that as described in the documentation the file name must end with `.rpm` and the default is (copied from the documentation) `<CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME>[-<component>].rpm` so this is the explanation why component part is always placed at the end.

There are quite a few tests for different CPack packagers here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Tests/RunCMake/CPack/tests
So you can explore those snippets as well.

P.S. contributions to the documentation are always welcome :)

Comment: I was using CPACK_RPM_`<component>`_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME instead of CPACK_RPM_`<component>`_FILE_NAME  (no package!) due to confusion with CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME.